# How do I find one pattern, then a second pattern, and then append text only after the second pattern using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to find a pattern in a file, then find a second pattern, and then add a line with text after the second pattern only.

For example, if this is the text in the file I'm trying to change:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
```

I want to match "aaa" and then "ddd" and then add "hello" to the line after "ddd".

I've tried

```
sed -i "/aaa/,/ddd/a\hello" foo.txt
```

but what I end up getting is:

```
aaa
hello
bbb
hello
ccc
hello
ddd
hello
eee
fff
ggg
```

edit: Also, is there a way to make sure this only occurs once, or only after the first occurrence of the second pattern ("ddd" in the example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/aaa/,/ddd/!b;/ddd/a\hello' file
```

EDIT:

If you want it only occur once in the file:

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/aaa/,/ddd/!b;/ddd/!b;h;a\hello' file
```

See John1024 solutions for an elegant use of Bash and Sed.

N.B. I would delete this answer if possible but SO does not allow an accepted answer to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed $'/aaa/,/ddd/ { /ddd/ a\hello\n }' patterns
```

The command in braces adds the line hello after any line matching ddd.  The command in braces, however, is only applied to lines between aaa and ddd.

Alternatively, using substitute rather than add:

```
sed '/aaa/,/ddd/ s/ddd/ddd\nhello/' patterns
```

This produces:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
hello
eee
fff
ggg
```

This version works by limiting the substitute to happen only after the aaa line has occurred.

**Alternative:**  Suppose that we only want to add hello after the first occurrence of ddd and only if aaa occurred beforehand.  In that case:

```
sed $'0,/ddd/ {/aaa/,/ddd/ { /ddd/ a\hello\n}}' patterns
```

The first range specifier, `0,/ddd/` limits the range of all that follows to just the lines up to the first occurrence of ddd.  The remainder of the command is as before.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That works. Is there a way to make the change only on the first occurrence of "ddd"?

Comment: As a marriage of sed and bash I think your solutions are more elegant and less contrived than mine.